# setting job.properties file in java code to launch an oozie action

Tags: java, hadoop, workflow, oozie

I am trying to launch an oozie action using java code. when using command line, we specify the properties file by "-config job.properties" and it knows which workflow to pick. How do we define the "job.properties" file in java code to do the same task?

```
    conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH,"hdfs://clusterdb05.com:8020/user/apps/merge-logs/workflow.xml");
    conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "jobtracker.com:8021");
    conf.setProperty("nameNode", "hdfs://namenode.com:8020");
    conf.setProperty("queueName", "jobtracker.com:8021");
    conf.setProperty("appsRoot", "hdfs://namenode.com:8020/user/apps");

    try {
        String jobId = wc.run(conf);

        System.out.println("Workflow job submitted");

        while (wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == WorkflowJob.Status.RUNNING) {
            System.out.println("Workflow job running ...");
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Workflow job completed ...");
        System.out.println(wc.getJobInfo(jobId));
    } catch (OozieClientException oozieClientException) {
        oozieClientException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how are you trying to invoke oozie through java, share code

Comment: @zuxqoj this code just runs the workflow and fails because its unable to fetch the properties file. what i want is just to define the properties file like we do for command line, and everything else moves forward from there. any help?

Comment: You don't how to handle job.properties?

Comment: @Chirag Did you get the answer to your question. If yes, please share

Answer (score 0):

It is example for `ResourceBundel`. Try to integrate with your program.

```
public class BundleTest {
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    public BundleTest() {
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("job");
    }

    public String getMessage(String id, Object... params) {
        String text = null;
        try {
            text = bundle.getString(id);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            text = "!! key " + id + " not found !!";
        }
        if (params != null) {
            MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(text);
            text = mf.format(params, new StringBuffer(), null).toString();
        }
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      BundleTest test = new BundleTest();
        String jobTracker = test.getMessage("jobTracker");
        String nameNode = test.getMessage("nameNode");
        String queueName = test.getMessage("queueName");
        String appsRoot = test.getMessage("appsRoot");
        System.out.println(jobTracker);
        System.out.println(nameNode);
        System.out.println(queueName);
        System.out.println(appsRoot);

        String message2 = test.getMessage("JOB_KEY_2", "Your First");
        System.out.println(message2);
    }
}
```

job.properties

```
jobTracker=jobtracker.com:8021
nameNode=hdfs://namenode.com:8020
queueName=jobtracker.com:8021
appsRoot=hdfs://namenode.com:8020/user/apps;
#With Parameter
JOB_KEY_2= {0} Job
```

Output :

```
jobtracker.com:8021
hdfs://namenode.com:8020
jobtracker.com:8021
hdfs://namenode.com:8020/user/apps;
Your First Job
```

Comment: what has this code to do anything with launching ann oozie action?

Comment: It is just used as configuration. The main purpose of `xx.properties` is to keep the content with key-value pair. Like `Map`

Comment: if i wanted to read each key value pair in my code, wouldn't directly using property.load("file") be much easier?

Comment: `property.load("file")` also same concept as I mention. Try to update your question. We cannot meet your target...

Comment: See, when we run an oozie action from command line, what we do is: "oozie job -oozie http://something/oozie -config job.properties -run". Now i want to do the same using java code. I dont want to specify oozieclient.APP_PATH, rather just the properties file

Comment: Honestly, I am not familiar with `oozie`. Here example with java http://www.infoq.com/articles/oozieexample